# CMake: Remove leading zero from timestamp components

Tags: cmake

I'm using cmake's [`configure_file()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html?highlight=configure_file) function to set some version information in a C build. The generated output looks like this:

```c
#pragma once

// Time
#define VERSION_HOUR        15
#define VERSION_MINUTE      53
#define VERSION_SECOND      56
```

I obtain these values via cmake's [`string(TIMESTAMP)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#timestamp) capabilities:

```
# Time
string(TIMESTAMP hour "%H")
string(TIMESTAMP min  "%M")
string(TIMESTAMP sec  "%S")
```

The problem I'm encountering is that the values returned by `string(TIMESTAMP)` have leading zeros. For example, I can end up with something like this:

```c
#pragma once

#define VERSION_HOUR        15
#define VERSION_MINUTE      03
#define VERSION_SECOND      06
```

In this case compilation of the code base will fail as there are parts in the code which basically look like this:

```c
const build_version_t build_version = {
    .hour   = VERSION_HOUR,
    .minute = VERSION_MINUTE,
    .second = VERSION_SECOND
}
```

Where `.hour`, `.minute` and `.second` are fields of type `uint8_t`.
Literals with a leading zero are interpreted as octal.

What is the easiest/best way to strip the leading zeros from the corresponding cmake variable(s)?

Comment: sooo `string(REGEX REPLACE ....` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are tons of ways to handle this. One way is to evaluate it using `math`. For example:

```
set(hour 09)
math(EXPR hour ${hour})
message(STATUS ">${hour}<")
```

Outputs:

```
-- >9<
```

(The angle brackets are only there to show that there are no other character in the final value of `hour`.)

Comment: Oh, this is so much nicer than the regex workaround I was using... thank you very much!